# Alternative to git ls-tree -r HEAD -- . :!foo

Tags: git, git-ls-tree

I want to retrieve a list of paths, permissions, and content hashes for files for revision in a set of paths, excluding some paths.

`git ls-tree` seems perfect. For example, in the Git repo,

```
$ git ls-tree -r v2.2.2 -- Documentation ':!Documentation/RelNotes'
100644 blob ddb030137d54ef3fb0ee01d973ec5cee4bb2b2b3    Documentation/.gitattributes
100644 blob 2c8b2d612ee0d6c1f687bfa062bb7fe6471d9280    Documentation/.gitignore
100644 blob 894546dd75416fcf09542096a67b2f22a7d0de7a    Documentation/CodingGuidelines
100644 blob 2f6b6aabd74a24abdb3ac189118095fcee19f8d2    Documentation/Makefile
100644 blob fa71b5f0b62f43483d02c24d809e6282fa49576a    Documentation/SubmittingPatches
100644 blob 2c16c536ba830ec12bbf335d09f689d23e325197    Documentation/asciidoc.conf
100644 blob 0cebc4f6927211ffbc013de9368f03f480dba65d    Documentation/blame-options.txt
100755 blob ba4205e0302a267a5da6bef504f3e69eb0c4aa6d    Documentation/build-docdep.perl
100755 blob 87437f8a95768595e040b8c4c1d48e5c29ada087    Documentation/cat-texi.perl
```

---

But this was [removed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5c6cb9888df9d21ddbb5c3478d511edcdf3cda7c) in 2.3.0, with the message

> ls-tree: disable negative pathspec because it's not supported

Well that's circular ;)

---

What is the new, "correct" way to do this in git 2.3.0 and later?

Comment: (I read "supported" in that message in the sense of "a feature for which anyone is willing to fix bugs and maintain codepaths", which leaves it a bit less circular than might otherwise be the case).

Comment: ...indeed, the changelog indicates that to be the case: Negative pathspecs were accepted by the parser, but didn't actually work.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, they did work, or at least the one I gave as an example for the git repo works.

Comment: And yet the person who first implemented them says they don't. Speaking of which -- the mailing list is public; why not inquire there?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I did. "Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently: git@vger.kernel.org"

Answer (score 1):

Piping through

```
awk '$4 !~ /Documentation\/RelNotes/ { print }'
```

...is the obvious approach. To make this a bit more generic:

```
s='Documentation/RelNotes'
awk -v exclusion_re="$s" '$4 !~ exclusion_re { print }
```

Comment: ...unless you happen to be one of those poor blokes who use Windows.

Comment: Well, I use Ubuntu. I was just pointing out the Windows issue that others may have. I didn't know awk was included.

Comment: Ahh. Fortunately, Git for Windows is the preferred way to run Git on Windows, and it bundles an msys build of awk, so... there we are.